# Discover Domain-Specific Attributes in Text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to search some Natural Language Processing technique to find special attributes in Text, like entrance, amount of parcels, color of cloth or other types using some supervised-learning or semi-supervised learning (I've tried Stanford Bootstrapped Entity Learning / SPIED).

I don't know exactly how can I search for that in other places. I've tried using Hidden Markov Chains and CRF Classifier for that purposes, but I didn't get the expected output.

Example:

"I want buy a new **black** car in **30 parcels** with **entrance of $1000**"

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have annotated corpus for this task?

Comment: @IstvanNagy Since they're simple patterns, I've a list of 100 training examples of each entity. That's why I tried to use a Bootstrapped Entity Learning

Comment: and thats why CRF doesnt work. Have you tried morphologically and syntactically analyze your text and extract patterns?

Comment: Those terms are not morphologically or syntactically "different". That's, since they are not quite common, and are basically numeral, the POS Tagger gives "NUM", or "N" in general when it's typed as "36x" (number of parcels) or "U$3000 of entrance" (NUM - N).